# CSS styles for select element are not applied in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

CSS border and background color styles are not applied to the `select` element in IE7.

HTML Code:

```
<select class="select_box">
   <option>xxx</option>
</select>
```

CSS code:

```
.select_box
{
border:1px solid #ddd;
background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the `background-color` [sort of being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exkdU.png) (I changed your colours to red)..

There's nothing you can do, and no easy workaround.

If you *really* want to do this in IE7, you'll have to use JavaScript to [swap the `select`s out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866796/css-custom-drop-down-menu/5867222#5867222); you can theme those however you like and it will work in all browsers (unless JavaScript is disabled, in which case you'd be left with what you had in the first place: a native `select` element).

Also relevant:

- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single/